# 10-Foot UI Carousel Layout Menu

Tags: java, user-interface

This is kind of hard to explain, but I want to make a UI, similar to  this

[image: screenshot]

in Java. I've been considering using [this library](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/), but are there better alternatives?